# Calculating transmission and reception delays

Tags: algebra-precalculus

There is a collection of nodes that can send messages to each other. Each node $n$ has a transmission delay $TD_n$ and a reception delay $RD_n$.

Every node sends a message that gets received by every other node and both the transmission and reception timestamps are recorded. This gives us $T_{n,m}$ as the total delay between the sending node $n$ and a receiving node $m$.

($T_{n,m} = TD_n + RD_m$)

I need to calculate the $TD$ and $RD$ of every node. All $T_{n,m}$ are known.

For a collection of 3 nodes ($1$, $2$, $3$), it would look like this:

$T_{1,2}=TD_1+RD_2$
$T_{1,3}=TD_1+RD_3$
$T_{2,1}=TD_2+RD_1$
$T_{2,3}=TD_2+RD_3$
$T_{3,1}=TD_3+RD_1$
$T_{3,2}=TD_3+RD_2$

Or in a matrix:

$
\begin{pmatrix} 
        & T_{1,2} & T_{1,3} \\
T_{2,1} &         & T_{2,3} \\
T_{3,1} & T_{3,2} &  
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
          & TD_1+RD_2 & TD_1+RD_3 \\
TD_2+RD_1 &           & TD_2+RD_3 \\
TD_3+RD_1 & TD_3+RD_2 &  
\end{pmatrix}$

To me it feels solvable, but so far my attempts have failed. Can it be solved? If so, how?

Comment: I believe the problem is underdetermined, you could add some $T$ to all the TD values, and subtract the same $T$ from each RD value to get infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like alexander.cliffe said, there probably isn't an answer. However, more information can be derived.

To demonstrate, we're using these numbers (that we don't officially know):
$TD = [16, 19, 11]$
$RD = [23, 19, 21]$

This would result in the following matrix:
\begin{pmatrix} 
   & 35 & 37 \\
42 &    & 40 \\
34 & 30 & 
\end{pmatrix}

With this, the differences between the different $TD$'s or $RD$'s can be calculated, which will allow us to fill in the blank spots. Let's do it for the $RD$'s.

$RD_2 - RD_1 = 30 - 34 = -4$
$RD_3 - RD_2 = 37 - 35 = 2$

$T_{1,1} = T_{1,2} - -4 = 35 + 4 = 39$
$T_{2,2} = T_{2,1} + -4 = 42 - 4 = 38$
$T_{3,3} = T_{3,2} + 2 = 30 + 2 = 32$

This is correct with our original $TD$ and $RD$ numbers. The matrix now looks like this:
\begin{pmatrix} 
39 & 35 & 37 \\
42 & 38 & 40 \\
34 & 30 & 32
\end{pmatrix}

We can now look at what the maximum value for each delay is. For each $TD$, it's the lowest value of the row and for $RD$ it's the lowest value of the column. The minimum value of the delays are their maximum value minus the lowest value of the entire matrix.

$\begin{pmatrix} 
39 & 35 & 37 \\
42 & 38 & 40 \\
34 & 30 & 32
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix} 
35 & 5 \\
38 & 8 \\
30 & 0
\end{pmatrix}$
$\begin{pmatrix} 
34 & 30 & 32 \\
 4 &  0 & 2
\end{pmatrix}$

As you can see, the maxima are conveniently the column and row that contain the lowest matrix value and the minima are the differences between the maxima and the lowest matrix value.

This is as far as you can calculate it. Every delay has the same range of 30. So now the only variable left, is the ratio between $TD_3$ and $RD_2$. It is provable that this works with the original numbers.

The original ratio is 19-11, or ~63.3%. This results in a delay of $(0.63333 * 30 =) 19$. We can now add 19 to all the $RD$ minima and (30-19=)11 to all the $TD$ minima which results in the original $TD$ and $RD$ numbers.

Of course we don't know what the ratio is when we don't know the original numbers. But the application I will use this for states that the ratio is 56-44 average.

Answer (score 1):

Following from my comment, writing the problem in matrix form
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
 1 &  &  &  & 1 &  \\ 
 1 &  &  &  &  & 1 \\ 
  & 1 &  & 1 &  &  \\ 
  & 1 &  &  &  & 1 \\ 
  &  & 1 & 1 &  &  \\ 
  &  & 1 &  & 1 &
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
TD_1 \\
TD_2 \\
TD_3 \\
RD_1 \\
RD_2 \\
RD_3
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
T_{1,2}\\
T_{1,3}\\
T_{2,1}\\
T_{2,3}\\
T_{3,1}\\
T_{3,2}
\end{pmatrix}\,,
$$
we see that the matrix is not invertible since the vector $(1,1,1,-1,-1,-1)$ is in its kernel.

Comment: You are probably right. But I have found a way to give a bit more information and reduce this problem to only 1 unknown variable. I'll post that as an answer.